# Making bot have different presence in different servers

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord command where users can change what my bot is playing, but it changes for all servers and I don't want that. Is there a way to make it so that it only changes for the server that the user is sending the command from?

So far all I have is this

```
games={}
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def game(ctx, name):
    server=ctx.message.server
    games[server.name] = await bot.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name=name))
```

Comment: @abccd I think an answer to that effect (and maybe a description of *why*) would be more useful than closing the question.

Comment: Also, I think this *might* be possible with sharding. You may want to upgrade to the rewrite version and look into the [`AutoShardedClient`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.AutoShardedClient) class. (I've never used shards so I'm not certain)

Comment: No there isn't a standard supported way, unless you seriously wanted it and start sharding (recommended to only use it for when you have **lots** of servers), which in that case, you can. I'm just leaving a comment here, someone else might want to write their answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as a Discord bot is only considered to have one websocket. You could make a [loop](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=loop#discord.ext.tasks.loop) and `asyncio.sleep(time)` to change the presence over time. Hope that helps!